# How to stop the timer function after the object has been shot?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am making a simple target shooting game.I have a countdownTimer inside the label and an object that blinks in a random position inside the panel. Every time I click on the object,. the object's timer stops which makes that object stop too, but the countdown timer doesn't and that is my problem. I want the countdown timer should stop also.

Could someone help me about this matter?

Here's the code :

```
 private void starting()
 {
    new Timer(TIMER_PERIOD, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (count++ < MAX_COUNT)
            {
                String text = "Time remaining: (" + (MAX_COUNT - count) + ") seconds left";
                setCountDownLabelText(text);
                Date date = new Date();
                setCountDownPanelText(date);

            }
            else
            {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                randomTimer.stop();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 5):

It strikes me that you don't understand the code at all, that you are unaware of the anonymous class created that is extending [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), which (if you'd seen the documentation) has a function `stop()` which does what you ask.

You need to store a reference to the Timer.

```
private javax.swing.Timer timer;

private void starting() {
    timer = new Timer(TIMER_PERIOD, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // do stuff

            // stop the timer
            timer.stop();

            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for mixing up separate classes a) the Timer to use in Swing is the one in the swing package (_not_ the one in util) b) the util.Timer has the method cancel, but no constructor taking an ActionListener c) the swing.Timer has no method cancel but a method stop.

Comment: @Charles Goodwin please change 1) java.util.Timer to the javax.swing.Timer, 2) timer.stop() , 3) link to todays Java6 or 7 API

Comment: For easier location of the latest JavaDocs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: I already got it. What kleopatra & Korbel said are absolutely true but anyways, thanks guys for your help. "SHARING IS CARING" ;-)

Comment: And the answer was? How did you fix it? :P

Comment: @charles simply I just add another if statement and a boolean to know if the object has been hit or not. I also set the boolean hit = true in the mouselistener. ;-)